# What does mean && between variables in line without if?

Tags: javascript

I have following line of code in javascript:

```
q && (c = q === "0" ? "" : q.trim());
```

WHat does it mean? I understand that `c` is equals either empty string or q.trim() result, but what does mean `q && ()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript optimizes boolean expressions. When `q` is `false`, the right hand side of the expression doesn't matter for the result, so it's not executed at all. So this is a short form of:

```
if( q ) {
    c = q === "0" ? "" : q.trim()
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "if (q)" ...

Answer (score 3):

It is a guard against undefined/null/false variables.

If `q` is not defined, `false` or set to `null`, the code short circuits and you don't get errors complaining about `null.trim()`

Another way to write that would be:

```
if(q) {
  c = q === "0" ? "" : q.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of clause to check wether q is defined.